# Where Delphi stores look and feel properties?

Tags: delphi

After changing a VCL project deploy platform from 32 bits to 64 bits, the application layout became Ugly like it was compiled with Delphi 7.

Before, the project was only deployed as 32bits application and now it is only deployed as 64bits application.

I couldn´t understand the reason for this, because I even deleted the dproj file and let Delphi create another one from scratch and id did not help.

[image]

As depicted above, the navbar icons lost it's alpha channel, and the grid lost the gradient title bar, also controls lost the rounded corners.

It looks like an application compiled with Delphi 7 although it was compiled wth 10.3.3 Rio.

Any help?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: Go to Project / Options / Application / Manifest and check "Auto Generate" and "Enable Runtime Themes".

Comment: Hi Andreas: Both configurations are already enabled.

Comment: The question was closed but both links mentioned as the solution are the same and they do not solve the problem.

Comment: OK, I have reopened your Q.

Comment: What is the operating system you are running your application on. Windows 10 and consequently Windows 11 have special compatibility mode for running old application which enables them to render windows of old application just as if they were ran on older operating systems like Windows 7 or even Windows XP. I'm not exactly sure which parameters does windows use to detect older application but it is possible that your application might be wrongfully detected as some legacy application. If you try to make a new project with just this form in it is it stil rendered wrong?

Comment: I figured out. It has to do with adding libeay32 and ssleay32 dlls as external resources to the application. Now I have to find out why yhis is happening

Answer (score 0):

I figured out.

I added Libeay32 and SSLEay32 dll files as an external resource and named the rc and res files with the same name as the project.

This way the projects resource got lost.

Solved creating the resource named as OpenSSL.rc and OpenSSL.res and problem solved.

Thank you guys for the help.